# Maintaining a list of minor errata / corrections / comments

Tags: publications, arxiv, errors-erratum, doi

I am wondering what options there are for maintaining a list of errata / minor misprints / clarifications to published research papers. Here, I mean errors/misprints that are not sufficiently serious that a journal would consider publishing an erratum, but whose correction would nonetheless be beneficial to readers.

I have in mind a system where authors (and possibly readers) can attach comments / list of corrections / clarifications to their papers in a straightforward way - ideally in a way that links to the relevant DOI / arXiv identifier.

It seems somewhat surprising that such a system is not already established - or perhaps it is and I have missed it? One concern is over the longevity of the system - I used to maintain some errata to my paper on my own wiki-style pages, but at some point this wiki folded and I lost all of the information (which I had unfortunately not backed up anywhere).

Answer (score 1):

It is called [PubPeer](https://pubpeer.com/).

In my experience it is not very popular.  It seems mostly biomedical researchers use it.

If it's minor, why do it?

Comment: This is a useful answer, but OP did explain why they want to do it: "correction would nonetheless be beneficial to readers."